# Explanation for this method to find incenter of triangle

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics

Euclidea is a mobile game that requires you to construct certain geometric structures using only a straightedge and a compass.

One of the levels requires you to consruct the incenter of a scalene triangle within some stipulated moves.
While scouring the internet, I came across [this solution](https://youtu.be/70RDTf2Pw-s)(the second method, starting from 0:27).

I have spent a good amount of time trying to understand the solution to no avail (especially the rescaling of the triangle) so I would be very grateful if anyone could explain the solution in a clear, step-wise manner.

Comment: Asking someone visit another site to watch a video just to understand what you're even talking about makes for a poor question. You should summarize the steps here. Also, note which aspects you *do* understand, so that prospective answerers don't waste time (theirs or yours) explaining those.

Comment: BTW: It looks like the solver rescaled the triangle just to make it easier to get at later points of intersection, since a bunch of circles and lines created crossings very near to one another. I don't think that counts as part of the solution *per se*.

Comment: I wasn't sure of how to explain only via pctures and I felt that the video did a much better job of explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution shown in the video is doing nothing more than constructing the perpendicular bisector of a side of an isosceles triangle whose apex angle is the same as the angle we want to bisect.

[image]

Refer to the figure above.  When the circle with center $A$ and radius $AC$ is drawn, it intersects $AB$ at $D$, so that $AC = AD$ and $\triangle ACD$ is isosceles.  Then $\angle CAB = \angle CAD$, and shares the same angle bisector $AF$.  But bisecting this angle is the same as constructing the perpendicular bisector of side $CD$.  How would you do that?  You'd just draw two circles with equal radii at centers $C$ and $D$ whose radius is more than half the distance between them.  These circles intersect at $F$.

Note that we do not need to choose $AC$ as the radius of circle $A$, nor do we need to choose $AC = AD$ as the radius of circles $C$ and $D$.  These choices were made simply because these points already existed in the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

$AE$ is the radical axis of the red and green circles ($\implies AE \perp BD$). Furthermore, $\triangle ABD$ is isosceles. These are enough to show that $AE$ is an angle bisector. Can you take it from here?

I'll be happy to answer your questions, but please show more effort (so that the question doesn't remain as a link-only problem) in the original post.

[image]